# Why does the N value increase to 2 and 3 in the printed output when the recursions of draw use n-1?

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I can't understand why the n value always becomes 1 after the if statement returns. Furthermore, I don't understand how the n value can increase if both recursions are using n-1. Can someone explain how these events happen? Comments are added in the output for further explanation of the question.

```
import turtle

bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.speed(1)

def draw(t, length, n):
    if n == 0:
        print("Return")
        return
    else:
        print('N in if statement =', n)
    angle = 50
    print("Pre forward, n =", n)
    t.fd(length * n)
    print("Pre left turn, n =", n)
    t.lt(angle)
    print("Pre draw 1, n =", n)
    draw(t, length, n-1)
    print("Pre right turn, n =", n)
    t.rt(angle*2)
    print("Pre draw 2, n =", n)
    draw(t, length, n-1)
    print("Pre left turn 2, n =", n)
    t.lt(angle)
    print("Pre backwards, n =", n)
    t.bk(length*n)
    print("Post backwards, n =", n)

draw(bob, 15, 3)




turtle.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
N in if statement = 3
Pre forward, n = 3
Pre left turn, n = 3
Pre draw 1, n = 3
N in if statement = 2
Pre forward, n = 2
Pre left turn, n = 2
Pre draw 1, n = 2
N in if statement = 1
Pre forward, n = 1
Pre left turn, n = 1
Pre draw 1, n = 1
Return
Pre right turn, n = 1 # how does n become 1 here after 0 was returned?
Pre draw 2, n = 1
Return
Pre left turn 2, n = 1
Pre backwards, n = 1
Post backwards, n = 1
Pre right turn, n = 2
Pre draw 2, n = 2
N in if statement = 1
Pre forward, n = 1
Pre left turn, n = 1
Pre draw 1, n = 1
Return
Pre right turn, n = 1
Pre draw 2, n = 1
Return
Pre left turn 2, n = 1
Pre backwards, n = 1
Post backwards, n = 1
Pre left turn 2, n = 2
Pre backwards, n = 2
Post backwards, n = 2
Pre right turn, n = 3
Pre draw 2, n = 3 # how is it possible for n to increase from 1 to 3 when both recursions subtract 1 from n?
N in if statement = 2
Pre forward, n = 2
Pre left turn, n = 2
Pre draw 1, n = 2
N in if statement = 1
Pre forward, n = 1
Pre left turn, n = 1
Pre draw 1, n = 1
Return
Pre right turn, n = 1
Pre draw 2, n = 1
Return
Pre left turn 2, n = 1
Pre backwards, n = 1
Post backwards, n = 1
Pre right turn, n = 2
Pre draw 2, n = 2
N in if statement = 1
Pre forward, n = 1
Pre left turn, n = 1
Pre draw 1, n = 1
Return
Pre right turn, n = 1
Pre draw 2, n = 1
Return
Pre left turn 2, n = 1
Pre backwards, n = 1
Post backwards, n = 1
Pre left turn 2, n = 2
Pre backwards, n = 2
Post backwards, n = 2
Pre left turn 2, n = 3
Pre backwards, n = 3
Post backwards, n = 3 # how is it possible for n to increase from 1 to 3 when both recursions subtract 1 from n?
```

Comment: Where is `draw` called?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Why should something be added to `n` in order to make `t.bk(length*n)` make the turtle go back?

Comment: Please correctly indent bob.speed() and draw(bob,15,3)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I just updated the question. Effectively, I want to understand how the turtle retraces its steps back to the starting point using `t.bk` and how the recursions work in the function draw.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure I understand what's confusing here. Can you clarify what about "backwards" doesn't make sense? `bk` is short for backwards, which is the opposite of forwards. So the turtle goes forward `length * n`, then turns a few times in such a way that they're left facing the same direction they started in, then goes backward `length * n`, leaving them where they started. Slow down the turtle's drawing speed or walk around your room, mimicing the movements (be careful when walking backwards, you might run into something). Or trace it out on paper if walking isn't an option.

Comment: When `draw()` is called with 3rd parameter `=0`, `n` actually is `1` because you call `draw()` by `n-1`: `n=1`, `draw()` receives `0`, on return `n` is still `1`.

Comment: @ack thank you so much, makes complete sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help visualize what's going on if instead of simply printing the value of `n`, we use `n` as an indentation depth for the debugging output:

```
import turtle

def draw(t, length, n):
    if n == 0:
        print('\t'*n, "Return")
        return

    print('\t'*n, "N in if statement =", n)

    angle = 50
    print('\t'*n, "Pre forward, n =", n)
    t.forward(length * n)
    print('\t'*n, "Pre left turn, n =", n)
    t.left(angle)
    print('\t'*n, "Pre draw 1, n =", n)
    draw(t, length, n-1)
    print('\t'*n, "Pre right turn, n =", n)
    t.right(angle*2)
    print('\t'*n, "Pre draw 2, n =", n)
    draw(t, length, n-1)
    print('\t'*n, "Pre left turn 2, n =", n)
    t.left(angle)
    print('\t'*n, "Pre backwards, n =", n)
    t.backward(length * n)
    print('\t'*n, "Post backwards, n =", n)

bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.speed('slowest')

draw(bob, 15, 3)

turtle.mainloop()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
             N in if statement = 3
             Pre forward, n = 3
             Pre left turn, n = 3
             Pre draw 1, n = 3
         N in if statement = 2
         Pre forward, n = 2
         Pre left turn, n = 2
         Pre draw 1, n = 2
     N in if statement = 1
     Pre forward, n = 1
     Pre left turn, n = 1
     Pre draw 1, n = 1
 Return
     Pre right turn, n = 1
     Pre draw 2, n = 1
 Return
     Pre left turn 2, n = 1
     Pre backwards, n = 1
     Post backwards, n = 1
         Pre right turn, n = 2
         Pre draw 2, n = 2
     N in if statement = 1
     Pre forward, n = 1
     Pre left turn, n = 1
     Pre draw 1, n = 1
 Return
     Pre right turn, n = 1
     Pre draw 2, n = 1
 Return
     Pre left turn 2, n = 1
     Pre backwards, n = 1
     Post backwards, n = 1
         Pre left turn 2, n = 2
         Pre backwards, n = 2
         Post backwards, n = 2
             Pre right turn, n = 3
             Pre draw 2, n = 3
         N in if statement = 2
         Pre forward, n = 2
         Pre left turn, n = 2
         Pre draw 1, n = 2
     N in if statement = 1
     Pre forward, n = 1
     Pre left turn, n = 1
     Pre draw 1, n = 1
 Return
     Pre right turn, n = 1
     Pre draw 2, n = 1
 Return
     Pre left turn 2, n = 1
     Pre backwards, n = 1
     Post backwards, n = 1
         Pre right turn, n = 2
         Pre draw 2, n = 2
     N in if statement = 1
     Pre forward, n = 1
     Pre left turn, n = 1
     Pre draw 1, n = 1
 Return
     Pre right turn, n = 1
     Pre draw 2, n = 1
 Return
     Pre left turn 2, n = 1
     Pre backwards, n = 1
     Post backwards, n = 1
         Pre left turn 2, n = 2
         Pre backwards, n = 2
         Post backwards, n = 2
             Pre left turn 2, n = 3
             Pre backwards, n = 3
             Post backwards, n = 3
```